# Putting symbols inside the padding for conversion specifiers

Tags: python

```
print("%-10s %-15s $%8.2f %8.2f %10.2f" % (first_name[i], last_name[i],
                pay_rate[i], hours[i], calculate_pay(hours[i], pay_rate[i])))
```

Please be gentle if this has already been answered. I could not find it and am new to Python and programming.

I am trying to get a dollar sign next to the number(the floats). That is inside the padding instead of having a space between the '$' and the numbers.

Desired Output:

```
Please enter your first name(leave blank to quit): daniel
Please enter your last name: johnson
Please enter your hourly pay: 15
Please enter your hours: 40
Please enter your first name(leave blank to quit): 
John       Smith              $10.00    40.00     $400.00
Daniel     Johnson            $15.00    40.00     $600.00
```

Comment: Example output would be useful.

Comment: first create string with `$` (ie. `$25.00`) and later use it as argument in your formating string

Answer (score 2):

I would just make a helper function. Also its recomended to use [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), rather than old style python formating with `%`:

```
def my_format(fn, ln, pr, h, cp):
    return "{:10s} {:>10s} {:>8s} {:8>.2f} {:<8s}".format(
        fn, ln, '$'+'{:0.2f}'.format(pr), h, '$'+'{:0.2f}'.format(cp))


print(my_format('John', 'Smith', 10, 40, 400.00))
print(my_format('Daniel', 'Johnson', 15, 50, 60))
```

results in:

```
John            Smith   $10.00 40.00 $400.00 
Daniel        Johnson   $15.00 50.00 $60.00
```

You can adjust formating numbers and formats themselfs to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You have that space because the floats are right aligned. You can add a leading `-` before the width specifier to make the float left aligned so they'll sit right next to the `$` sign without any spaces:

```
>>> '$%8.2f' % 4.0
'$    4.00'
>>> # left align to remove space
>>> '$%-8.2f' % 4.0
'$4.00    '
```

With new-style formatting:

```
>>> '${:<8.2f}'.format(4.0)
'$4.00    '
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. There is no way to put the $ inside of the % like %$8.2f right?

Comment: @Derrick Nope. Although one could pad using the new style, it's not what we want here.